# Get the WIFI ID in android

Tags: android, wifi, ssid

I have checked similar questions and I got this far:

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
 WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
 String wifiInfo2 = wifiInfo.toString();
```

This returns a long line:
SSID: WiredSSID, BSSID: etc....

What I want to print is the WIFI the phone is connected too. In this case "SKYsomething".
Is there a way to get the wifi that the phone is connected to? ex:IF I connect my phone to "SKYtest", is there a way to get that name through code?
I tried to keep it simple and direct but i could be missing something. 
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
     WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
     WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
     String wifiInfo2 = wifiInfo.getSSID();
```

And if you preffer this is better solution:

```
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    String ssid = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSSID();
```

Dont forget to add in your manifest the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I've added the permission in the manifest. I do have a question though, do I add this line to the xml? I tried it as code on it's own and I got this error: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSSID() from the type WifiInfo

Comment: Hi, i eddited my question so you understand it better.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it to work. The problem was that the emulator doesn't connect to the wifi. It uses the computers Internet which is why I was getting a "wiredwifi" message. After I used what you told me I exported it to my phone and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help!